# load json data to dataset in d3js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am having json file like this. It contains some data.

```
[{\"Frequency\":\"Building 1\",\"Data\":[{\"Name\":\"Medicine\",\"Value\":46,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":22},{\"Name\":\"food\",\"Value\":32,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":12}]},{\"Frequency\":\"Building 2\",\"Data\":[{\"Name\":\"Medicine\",\"Value\":48,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":23},{\"Name\":\"food\",\"Value\":34,\"Value1\":33,\"Value2\":12}]},{\"Frequency\":\"Building 3\",\"Data\":[{\"Name\":\"Medicine\",\"Value\":57,\"Value1\":22,\"Value2\":24},{\"Name\":\"food\",\"Value\":42,\"Value1\":16,\"Value2\":11}]},{\"Frequency\":\"Building 4\",\"Data\":[{\"Name\":\"Medicine\",\"Value\":59,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":33},{\"Name\":\"food\",\"Value\":44,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":35}]},{\"Frequency\":\"Building 5\",\"Data\":[{\"Name\":\"Medicine\",\"Value\":62,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":11},{\"Name\":\"food\",\"Value\":48,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":3}]},{\"Frequency\":\"Building 6\",\"Data\":[{\"Name\":\"Medicine\",\"Value\":62,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":21},{\"Name\":\"food\",\"Value\":47,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":24}]},{\"Frequency\":\"Building 7\",\"Data\":[{\"Name\":\"Medicine\",\"Value\":58,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":22},{\"Name\":\"food\",\"Value\":43,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":22}]},{\"Frequency\":\"Building 8\",\"Data\":[{\"Name\":\"Medicine\",\"Value\":48,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":2},{\"Name\":\"food\",\"Value\":34,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":33}]}]
```

I want to store this json file into dataset in d3.js. or

I have given all data are static into my code. I want to give these data from json file to d3.js  can any one give me example.

my expected result is

```
dataset = JSON.parse("[{\"Frequency\":\"Building 1\",\"Data\":[{\"Name\":\"Medicine\",\"Value\":46,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":22},{\"Name\":\"food\",\"Value\":32,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":12}]},{\"Frequency\":\"Building 2\",\"Data\":[{\"Name\":\"Medicine\",\"Value\":48,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":23},{\"Name\":\"food\",\"Value\":34,\"Value1\":33,\"Value2\":12}]},{\"Frequency\":\"Building 3\",\"Data\":[{\"Name\":\"Medicine\",\"Value\":57,\"Value1\":22,\"Value2\":24},{\"Name\":\"food\",\"Value\":42,\"Value1\":16,\"Value2\":11}]},{\"Frequency\":\"Building 4\",\"Data\":[{\"Name\":\"Medicine\",\"Value\":59,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":33},{\"Name\":\"food\",\"Value\":44,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":35}]},{\"Frequency\":\"Building 5\",\"Data\":[{\"Name\":\"Medicine\",\"Value\":62,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":11},{\"Name\":\"food\",\"Value\":48,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":3}]},{\"Frequency\":\"Building 6\",\"Data\":[{\"Name\":\"Medicine\",\"Value\":62,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":21},{\"Name\":\"food\",\"Value\":47,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":24}]},{\"Frequency\":\"Building 7\",\"Data\":[{\"Name\":\"Medicine\",\"Value\":58,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":22},{\"Name\":\"food\",\"Value\":43,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":22}]},{\"Frequency\":\"Building 8\",\"Data\":[{\"Name\":\"Medicine\",\"Value\":48,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":2},{\"Name\":\"food\",\"Value\":34,\"Value1\":26,\"Value2\":33}]}]");
```

inside the bracket my data should be come i dont know how to do this can any tell me how to do this.

before i tried this but it is not working.

```
  d3.json("D3json.json", function(error, data) {
            var datas = data; 
        })
```

here is my jsfiddle example: [Click here to see the example](https://jsfiddle.net/eby9cxmq/)

Thanks 
Vinoth S

Comment: `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: that is not return any data

Comment: here i have attached my example just see this : https://jsfiddle.net/eby9cxmq/  I want use to bind data from json file can any one tell me how to change this code.

Comment: I looked at the jsfiddle and everything looks fine, the bar chart has the data from the json.

Comment: no the data are coming from dyanamically. that is i am asking how to do that in json

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are trying to dynamically load JSON data in contrast to having it hard-coded in your file.

Here is an example how to do it: http://bl.ocks.org/Jverma/887877fc5c2c2d99be10

In general, you have to execute the drawing part **after** you successfully loaded the data (within the callback function of d3.json())